# Insert lines in a file (YML) from specific line

Tags: php, yaml

I would like to insert lines into a file using PHP but from a specific line in the file.

My file acme.yml has a line `shortcuts:`. I want to insert some lines before it.

```
#newlines here
shortcuts:
```

I saw the functions `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` in the PHP Manual, but I don't know if it is the best approach.

```
<?php
    $file = 'acme.yml';
    $newlines = array($line1, $line2, $line3);

    $current = file_get_contents($file);

    #TODO:

    file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Maybe there are a better way to do it in yml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = 'acme.yml';
$newlines = array($line1, $line2, $line3);

$current = file_get_contents($file);

$current = str_replace("shortcuts:\n", implode("\n", $newlines) . "\nshortcuts:\n", $current);

file_put_contents($file, $current);

?>
```

Try this.